# Excel macro for changing ID value's

Tags: excel, vba

> For example:

- 695678 needs to be 1
- 695678 needs to be 1
- 695678 needs to be 1
- 695678 needs to be 1
- 695683 needs to be 2
- 695683 needs to be 2
- 695683 needs to be 2
- 696217 needs to be 3
- 696217 needs to be 3

I got this list of ID's (every number corresponds to a person) However these numbers for example 695678, 695683, 696217 don't go up by one. They are all ranked from low to high. Is there a way to automatically change these values to 1,2,3,... and so on by changing the lowest value to 1 and the second lowest value to 2 and so on. (can't figure out how to do it with macro's)

One note is that the IDs are repeated as these people made more then one transaction.

thanks!

Comment: 1) are this ID's always sorted? 2) would you like a formula or it shoulb be VBA?

Comment: Yes they are all sorted! They are always under each other. However one person may have 3 rows while another person can have 8 lines. Depends ont their number of transactions. Well what do you think would be the best solution?

Comment: user3297604, I should mentioned, that @Gary's Student solution was absolutely correct, while David Vandenbroucke's - Not! It will give you wrong result in case if you have two different ID's with count 1. In example: 6666, 6666, **6667, 6668,** 6669,6669. David's solutions gives uncorrect result: `1,1,2,2,3,3` (and it's wrong!), while Gary's solution gives you correct result: `1,1,2,3,4,4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Gary's Student, your solution close to perfect, I've looked into this and added a small correction, Compiling it gives an runtime error, your K value is 1 and in your else clause it just takes the same value again.

After adjusting it to their excel file it worked perfect:

```
Sub Renumber()
Dim N As Long, I As Long, OldValue As Long
Dim K As Long
K = 1
N = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
OldValue = Cells(2, 2).Value
For I = 2 To N
    If Cells(I, 2).Value = OldValue Then
        Cells(I, 2).Value = K
    Else
        OldValue = Cells(**I + 1**, 2).Value
        K = K + 1
        Cells(I, 2) = K
    End If
Next I
End Sub
```

The I + 1 between ** is the part that bugged. 
I've also changed the cell indexes accordingly.

Kind regards,

David

Answer (score 3):

If you require a **VBA** solution, then:

```
Sub Renumber()
    Dim N As Long, I As Long, OldValue As Long
    Dim K As Long
    K = 1
    N = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    OldValue = Cells(1, 1).Value
    For I = 1 To N
        If Cells(I, 1).Value = OldValue Then
            Cells(I, 1).Value = K
        Else
            OldValue = Cells(I, 1).Value
            K = K + 1
            Cells(I, 1) = K
        End If
    Next I
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),1,IF(A1=A2,B1,B1+1))
```

copied down to suit (with a blank in the top row of data).

To try to clarify, assumes data is in ColumnA but starting in A2 (A1 and B1 being blank), that the formula above is placed in B2 and copied down to suit.

First the test is whether A1 is blank (if True, returns `1`  the start point - though this could be keyed into B2 and a simpler formula then used in B3 and so on). If A1 is not blank then there is a further test, whether or not the value has changed. If it has not (True), then use the value immediately above, if it has changed (False) use the value immediately above incremented by one.

Comment: I'm trying to change some things but still not working. I'll give it another shot. I hope it's going to work now

Answer (score 0):

Another formula incase your data ever needs to be unsorted, and should be faster then any Macros:

```
=SUMPRODUCT( (FREQUENCY($A$1:$A$9, $A$1:$A$9) > 0) * (A1 >= $A$1:$A$10) )
```